# flex spacer automatic grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make tournament brackets with flexbox.

A flashscore example is [here](https://www.flashscore.com/soccer/europe/europa-league/?t=f5nverwq&ts=W694zFU9)

But I can't make gaps between second row. [my codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmgMPW)

```css
.brackets {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.round {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 31px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.round__item-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ea1312;
}
.round__item-spacer {
  min-height: 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.round__game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}
.round__game-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.round__game-spacer:first-child, .round__game-spacer:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="brackets mt-3">
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-spacer"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="round__game-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The main difficulity is that I don't know how many participants will be there

How can I do that?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I can't make gaps between second row

You could use `flex: 1` on `.round__game`, and they will stretch and fill their parents, and then, with `justify-content: center` you get this

*Note 1: I removed all the "space" elements, as they are not needed. If you will need a gap/gutter somewhere, use margins instead.*

> The main difficulity is that I don't know how many participants will
>   be there

I doubled up the initial row, so you can see this work w/o knowing how many participants.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdXYQX)

Stack snippet

```css
.brackets {
  display: flex;
}

.round {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.round__item-wrapper {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ea1312;
}
.round__game {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.round:first-child .round__game {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="brackets mt-3">
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

And with `justify-content: space-around` you get this

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqZoYx)

Stack snippet 2

```css
.brackets {
  display: flex;
}

.round {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.round__item-wrapper {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ea1312;
}
.round__game {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.round:first-child .round__game {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="brackets mt-3">
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
        <div class="round__game">
            <div class="round__game">
                <div class="round__item-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```